# How to view the year of a date in Google Calendar for Android

Tags: google-calendar, accessibility

I would like to know, something very easy. How do I figure out the year of a section of the scrollable list of days I am viewing in the Google Calendar app for Android?

Here is a screenshot.

> [image: section of Google Calendar]

I don't see the year anywhere.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Calendar only displays the year *when it is not the current year.***

Compare the following screenshots when it is not the current year (previous year and next year)

[image: Dec 2022] [image: Jan 2024]

with when it is the current year.

[image: March (2023)]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144950/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-t-how-to-view-the-year-of-a-date-in-google-calen); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.